# How to show same content with <php if ?> if i have few types tha need same content

Tags: php

it may be easy answer but I'm stuck in one of my project in

I want to show text if few of my collection or function are in there , sorry for my question I'm not sure  how to call them.

here's what I mean

```
<?php if($doc->type == "mp3"): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want here to find few of "dic types" and to show the same 
I can do them one by one but it will be load of codes and i think it may be some solutions like:

```
<?php if($doc->type == "mp3", "mp4", "doc" etc....): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to chose between few types and show same text ,, 
My solutions for now is to add them one by one

```
<?php if($doc->type == "mp3"): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($doc->type == "mp4"): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($doc->type == "doc"): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If is any way how to do it it would be great and really appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple ways to do it. One of the simpler is to use `in_array`

```
<?php if(in_array($doc->type, ['doc', 'mp3', 'mp4'])): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: oh thank you so much ,, Ive tried this but without `in_array` it works now

Answer (score 1):

Use a SWITCH case:

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Example:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake";
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (*|| for 'OR', && for 'AND'*) to combine several conditions in the same expression?

```
<?php if($doc->type == "mp3" || $doc->type == "mp4"): ?>
 <p> text and some other html here </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried with && and it didn't work  , with || it does work :)

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php for details about using PHP logical operators.

Comment: Yeah thank you ,, I can understand now why it wasn't working with && ,,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`switch() control structure`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> The statement list for a case can also be empty, which simply passes
>   control into the statement list for the next case.

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    echo "i is less than 3 but not negative";
    break;
case 3:
    echo "i is 3";
}
?>
```